# Return a copy of an order to the orderer as well as sales

Tags: forms, html-email

I have an order form that needs to email a copy of the order to the dealer, as well as to customer service for fulfillment. It needs to pick up the dealer's email off of the form field.  http://seminolefeed.com/seminole_order_form.html -thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs to post the data to your web server, where a handler (that you write/wrote) will send the email.